# Can I have multiple php.ini files?

Tags: windows, configuration, php

I want to set the `include_path` variable in my *php.ini* file (`C:\Windows\php.ini`).

But, I want different `include_path` values for different sites hosted on the same Windows server. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php says:

> php.ini is searched for in these locations (in order):
>
> . . .

You can review this list and see if one of the techniques helps in your case.  For example, you can set the environment variable `PHPRC`, or you can put a different php.ini file in each current working directory, assuming each virtual host has a distinct cwd.

Note that when using Apache and mod_php, or other module embedding PHP in the web server (e.g. FastCGI), the php.ini file is read once, at web server startup.  When you use PHP in a CGI manner, the php.ini file is read during every web request, so you have more opportunity to use a different php.ini.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the php include_path from an .htaccess file, assuming you have the correct AllowOverride settings in your httpd.conf file.  Here's an example how:

.htaccess

```
php_value include_path "d:\path\to\include"
```

Comment: The question never mentions Apache.

Comment: The question DOES mention Windows.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the question, its more important to have individual include paths for each server/site then multiple php.ini files? Id say keep your code in PHP as far as possible.

Then you can just set the include_path with [`set_include_path or ini_set`](http://no.php.net/set_include_path).

In apache you can set it in virtual domain or .htaccess file with `php_value include_path  "<first path to look>:<second path>:<etc>:."`. IIS probably has a similar method.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can.  However, some webservers can change PHP settings on an individual basis... Apache using mod_php has the php_value setting that you can set on various virtual hosts,  IIS might have something similar, but I'm not sure.

[`set_include_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) can also override the include path at runtime.

P.S. TF2 Engineer for the win.